# What types of list do we need?

Tags: list

As a SP developer and Architecture I have been getting lots of request to do this and that.

I like to create a list to track these requests. What type list should I create?

Comment: You're not much of an SP architect if you're asking this question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either provision a Tast List or Issue Tracking List. Task list is more like what you are going to need.

Answer (score 3):

Bill Baer has mentioned the correct lists to meet your needs.

You can read more about these lists on SharePoint blogs and articles. For your reference by time you may refer these articles:

[SharePoint Task Lists](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/sharepoint-task-lists-what-are-they-good-for.aspx)

[SharePoint Issue Tracking List](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=154)

Thanks & Best Regards